# Displaying rational numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two integer numbers m,n which together form a rational number in the form of m/n. Now I just want to display them in Matlab in this rational form.

I can do this by doing

```
char(sym(m/n))
```

So, if, e.g. `m = 1`, `n = 2`, Matlab will display `1/2`. However, if `m = 2`, `n = 4`, I am also getting `1/2`, whereas I want to get `2/4`.

Any way of doing this without recurring to something like

```
fprintf( '%d/%d', m, n )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the display format to `rat`

```
>> format rat
>> 2/3
ans =
       2/3
```

otherwise you can call [`rats`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rats.html) function

```
>> rats(2/3)
ans =
      2/3     
>> class(ans)
ans =
char
```

However, in both cases the fractions will be reduced. To avoid that you should create your separate function or introduce it as an anonymous function

```
>> rat2 = @(m,n) num2str([m n], '%d/%d')
rat2 = 
    @(m,n)num2str([m,n],'%d/%d')
>> rat2(2,4)
ans =
2/4
```

Comment: Seems like the OP wants `2/4` to be displayed as `2/4` itself

Comment: @SanthanSalai True, `rat` is just going to simplify it to `1/2`, which is what the OP explicitly said they don't want.